# Type mismatch: inferred type is Alignment.Vertical but FiniteAnimationSpec<IntSize> was expected

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

We had the following code, which was working just fine in Compose version **1.0.5**.

```kotlin
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
private fun AnimateContent(dismissState: DismissState, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = !dismissState.isDismissed(DismissDirection.StartToEnd)
                && !dismissState.isDismissed(DismissDirection.EndToStart),
        enter = fadeIn() + expandVertically(Alignment.Top),  // Compile error
        exit = fadeOut() + shrinkVertically(Alignment.Top)   // on these lines
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

However, after upgrading to **1.1.0-rc03**, we are getting the following build time error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Alignment.Vertical but
> FiniteAnimationSpec was expected

I've researched online, but unfortunately there is close to no information on what this error is or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they changed the order of arguments of `expandVertically` and `shrinkVertically`, the first argument is now `animationSpec` and direction is second, just use named argument:

```kotlin
expandVertically(expandFrom = Alignment.Top)
shrinkVertically(shrinkTowards = Alignment.Top)
```